# Storing user information in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently working on an ATM program, the program prompts a user to enter their username and password so they can access their account. I've been asked to use an array to store this information, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to go about it. Here's what my professor has written:

In main initialize an Account array with the following Account objects:

```
Account1               Account2             Account3
Account Num: 123       Account Num: 456     Account Num: 789
Account Pin: abc123    Account Pin: def456  Account Pin: ghi789
Balance: 100.00        Balance: 50.00       Balance: 200.00
```

How would I store this information in one array? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you know what classes are? What structures are? Your professor obviously meant an array of classes or structures. In general, if you have a question about an assignment the best resource for you to get help would be your instructor. They are paid to help you learn, that's their job. Have you tried asking your instructor for a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `Account` class to hold all information for one account in a single place:

```
class Account {
public:
    std::size_t m_num;
    std::string m_pin;
    std::size_t m_balance;  // alternative use double here
};
```

Then declare and initialize the array, an object of type `Account[3]`, with braced initialization (C++11):

```
Account account[3] = {
   {123, "abc123", 100}, ...  
};
```